# Cassandra UDT mapping issue

Tags: cassandra

I am not able to map data which has UDT type.

The table is definition is the following.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS members_data.Test(
  priority   int,
  name text,
  test_links  list<frozen<TestLinks>>,
  PRIMARY KEY(name)
);
```

The model is the following.

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonSerialize
@Table(keyspace="members_data", caseSensitiveKeyspace=false, caseSensitiveTable=false, name="Test")
public class Test{

@Column(name="name", caseSensitive=false)
private String name;

@Column(name="priority", caseSensitive=false)
private int priority;

@Frozen
@Column(name="test_links", caseSensitive=false)
private List<TestLinks> test_links;
```

---

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonSerialize
@UDT(keyspace = "members_data", name = "Testlinks")
public class TestLinks {

@Field(name = "test_link")
private String test_link;

@Field(name = "link_title")
private String link_title;
```

The mapper usage.

```
MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(sessionManager.getSession());
manager.udtCodec(TestLinks.class);
Mapper<Test> mapper = manager.mapper(Test.class);
Result<Test> result = mapper.map(testResultSet);
test = result.one();  //test object would be null here
```

the `cassandra-driver-mapping` is `3.1.0`.

Mapper is not throwing any error and now even mapping data to model. Could someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: 1) What is the error exactly? Can you show the stack trace or the message? 2) You are not showing the CQL definition of TestLinks 3) You are using the map() method with an external ResultSet (testResultSet variable), but you are not showing where this variable comes from. 4) Are you sure that testResultSet contains all the required fields?

Comment: Thanks Adutra. It turns out before mapping I was calling `testResultSet.one()` and that was making resultset null and mapping was not happening.